# Custom ngx-translate loader, receiving cannot set property 'http' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ngx-translate

I'm setting up a Ionic 4 project using ngx-translate and a custom loader to load JSON translations from an external domain. I've been following this guys take on it: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngx-translate-translatehttploader-with-external-url/99331/4

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-jdfbh6

So this is my custom loader (provider).

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslationProvider implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello TranslationProvider Provider');
  }

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.get<any>(Environment.base_api + '/static/translations/' + lang + 'json', {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).subscribe((res: Response) => {
        observer.next(res.json());
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and in my app.module.ts (imports):

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(App),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  HttpClientModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (TranslationProvider),
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })
],
```

The error message I receive is:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'http' of undefined at TranslationProvider (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1073:19)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a working sample app, here's the gist:
https://gist.github.com/olivercodes/a34be66e5b69edcd96038e5a4518b16e

You need to change @Injectable() to

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Also, make sure these are your import locations:

```
// In the service file
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'

// in app.module
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Use my provided gist and make sure your imports are right.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the input.

I've tried doing it your way, but it seems to keep telling me that http is undefined.

You can view my stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-jdfbh6